# how to place dojo widget like text button on google map as custom control

Tags: google-maps-api-3, dojo

I am trying to place a dojo button on google map. How to do this ? I tried creating button like

```
 var tbutton = new dijit.form.Button({id: "showUsers", label: "User"}); 

controlUI.appendChild(tbutton);
```

(controlUI is parent div which gets placed on map)

also tried

```
 controlUI.appendChild(tbutton.domNode);
```

None of them work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [dojo.place](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/place)

```
dojo.place(tbutton.domNode, controlUI);
```

Comment: It worked with directly creating a widget in map rather then having it under div...But this one gave some clue..Thanks